# Unity show up after several times booting and logging in, but then stops doing so

Tags: unity

I have a similar problem as mentioned in [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) .

When I installed 16.04 on my PC, it booted correctly. I could login and Unity showed up. However, after several days of booting and logging in Unity suddenly stopped showing up and the screen looks like the attached photo in the link given above. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu several times ever since, but the problem persists.

What can I do?

Comment: What graphics and what drivers are you running?

Comment: Did you follow the advice of the answers on the page?